# What is Package.xml in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, package

In various extension, I saw package.xml file but I did not use that. I want to know that should I use that or not ? Basically what is the need of package.xml in magento. I always found that it is placed on root of site.
But Confuse about use that. Is it Harmful for site if I place that on root?Should I also create package.xml while creating extension in magento ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually whenever we create a new extension and upload it to magento website, we create that file.It is just a simple file containing details regarding that extension, authors, file/folder path.It is not at all harmfull.It can be generated via backend in system->magento connect->package extension.If are developing a module then it is usefull to you otherwise ignore it!

Answer (score 2):

extension manifest file containing details regarding that extension, authors, file/folder path .
it can be use to install plugin by back end
When the folder-structure also contains a file called package.xml, there is chance that you can skip the procedure place and modify by manually  alltogether. Instead, login to your MagentoConnect Manager (within the Magento backend) and try to upload the ZIP-file as a package.